# Can't attach jQuery Plugins that is inside {{#if}} in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my emberjs app. I have bunch of jquery plugins that I need to bind to various elements.

I am using this piece of code to initiate jquery plugins for elements.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        window.appPluginsInit(); // all jquery plugin init

        // chart client init
        var chartClientSettings = {
            serverUrl: config.ajaxUrl
        };

        this.$('.chart-client').chartClient(chartClientSettings);
    }
});
```

This only works for element that are initially loaded to the page. But for example if an element is under `{{#if}}` it doesn't seem to be attached with plugins.

**Works**

`<button class="chart-client">Show Chart</button>`

**Doesn't work**

Considering the `someVar` is false on initial load.

```
{{#if someVar}}
<button class="chart-client">Show Chart</button>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your `.chart-client` element a component and init the plugin on the components `didInsertElement`.

Component template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/chart-client">
  Show Chart
</script>
```

Component:

```
App.ChartClientComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ["chart-client"],
  tagName: "button",
  chartClientSettings = {
    serverUrl: config.ajaxUrl
  },
  didInsertElement: function () {
      this.$().chartClient(this.get("chartClientSettings"));
  }
});
```

Application view:

```
{{#if someVar}}
{{chart-client}}
{{/if}}
```

JSBin example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wemujo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Alternatively you could also just observe (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/observers/) when someVar changes to true, but I think the component way is better, especially as you say that you have many elements that you'll need to bind

Comment: Thanks, ended up using components.

Answer (score 1):

The if is parsed after jQuery, delay the jQuery action:

```
setTimeout((function () {
    this.$('.chart-client').chartClient(chartClientSettings);
}).bind(this), 1);
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @Pete TNT is the best but I see 2 other options:

1) instead of putting things in if block, you can probably just use css to show/hide the button. That way the ".chart-client" is always in the DOM tree and hence you can apply the plugin to the element.

```
<button  {{bind-attr class=":chart-client someVar:show:hide"}}>Show Chart</button>
```

2) Add an observer(also as suggested by @Pete TNT) : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jekuvixufo/1/
(I would not have posted this but I was already writing a jsbin so I thought why waste my effort.)